# Why won't my site's preview image show on a Facebook share?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, webforms

I'm pulling my hair out on this one.  I'm trying to share my ASP.Net Web Forms site on Facebook, but the preview doesn't show the Image or Description I have set up.  I found this chunk of code that's *supposed* to do the trick.  I put it in my MasterPage, but it just isn't working:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
        <title>MySite</title>
        <meta property="og:url"           content="http://www.example.com" />
        <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
        <meta property="og:title"         content="Your Website Title" />
        <meta property="og:description"   content="Your description" />
        <meta property="og:image"         content="http://www.example.com/img/fbbanner.jpg" />
...
```

According to Facebook's Sharing Debugger,

> The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value
>   can be inferred from other tags.

...but, hell if I know what that's supposed to mean.  What's funny is, if I remove the meta tags out entirely, I get the same error.  When I click on "See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL,"  I see the meta tags in the rendered code... I'm at a total loss.  I can't find an article or an answer that was written in the past several years, so I have a feeling the information I'm getting is outdated.  I just can't figure out the magic words...

***Update*** Now, suddenly it works fine.  I just clicked "Scraped Again" after I posted this, and it seems to be working.  I don't really get it... :(

Answer (score 0):

if you are using any cache plugin, make sure you clear all your caches. Also make sure the image you are using has the recommended facebook size: 1200(w) x 630(h) or 600 x 315. If not it will choose randomly some of your images in the website that are suiting the facebook needs. Read more [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices)

Comment: Cache is my favorite thing about web development... not only do you have to get syntax exactly right, but you also have to cross your fingers when you refresh your browser.

Comment: by refreshing your browser any cache plugin you may be using won't delete its files.